# How to extract OrderID from a div element in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, regex, selenium, xpath

I need to extract just the OrderID from a div element for selenium testing using C#. Below is my code:

```
    public static string GetOrderId(IWebDriver instance)
    {
       var orderIdText = instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//*
       [@id='contentArea']/div[1]/div/div/div[1]")).Text;            
       //Need to extract OrderID from the orderIdText.
       return orderId;
}
```

div element goes like this:

```
<div>Thank you for requesting a record through the Record Request service. Your order number for this transaction is KR589497.
     <p>Your credit card has been charged ............. </p>
</div>
```

I need OrderId= KR589497 and return this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: From OP's comments, the string you are matching can have differing formats:

```
"Your **order** number for this transaction is KR589497."
"Your **confirmation** number for this transaction is MT289555."
```

Since you are only interested in the "OrderID", to create a regular expression from the two strings, you want take the greatest possible "union" of these strings:

```
" number for this transaction is {OrderID}."
```

This also means that a "smaller" union of the two strings will also cause a match:

```
"transaction is {OrderID}."
```

---

Here is a solution using a regular expression:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@" number for this transaction is ([^\.]+)\.",
    RegexOptions.Compiled);
Match match = regex.Match(orderIdText);
if (match.Success)
{
    string orderId = match.Groups[1].Value; // "KR589497"
}
```

---

Regular expression explained:

```
" number for this transaction is ([^\.]+)\."
```

- `number for this transaction is` - match string exactly
- `([^\.]+)` - match one or more characters, excluding `.` character

  - this is the `orderId`, you can add business rules as you see fit
- `\.` - match `.` character exactly

Comment: Using regex didn't get into the if condition. So order id is null.

Comment: What is the string returned into `orderIdText`?

Comment: orderIdText = "Thank you for requesting a record through the Record Request service. Your order number for this transaction is KR589497.\r\nYour credit card has been charged $66.35. You will receive an email notification indicating whether your order can be filled."

Comment: FYI: There is <p> inside <div> so it will return what's inside <p> as well. So I need to strip that too.

Comment: I do not know if we are missing something. But "match.Success" is returning false.

Comment: Yeah... not sure, but the dotnetfiddle I linked does work with the string that you provided. Can you confirm this?

Comment: I tried in dotnetfiddle. It didn't. Here is my string:

    "Thank you for requesting a record through the Record Request service. Your confirmation number for this transaction is MT289555.\r\nYour credit card has been charged $66.35. Once your order has been reviewed, you will receive an email notification indicating whether your order can be filled (based on availability of records, eligibility, etc.)."

Can u try with this string please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147861/discussion-between-budi-and-ranp).

Answer (score 0):

Grab the entire element and call it OrderIdText, then try something like the following:

```
var OrderId = OrderIdText.substring(OrderIdText.indexOf("is"), OrderIdText.indexOf("."));
```

You will most likely have to modify the above by a character or two, but should be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for calculating order ID will be:

```
var orderID= orderIdText.substring(orderIdText.lastIndexOf("is")+3, orderIdText.lastIndexOf(".",orderIdText.indexOf("\r")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Monika. But it is returning
    
    OrderId= "KR589497.\r\nYour credit card has been charged $66.35. Once your order has been reviewed, you will receive an email notification indicating w". 
I need to strip off the remaining chars  after the "." as well

Comment: I am making some modifications. Please check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the updates. But it isn't still working and returning same string as above.

Comment: It should work. I have tried it at my end. Please copy the same code.

Comment: Can you try with this string "Thank you for requesting a record through the Record Request service. Your confirmation number for this transaction is MT289555.\r\nYour credit card has been charged $66.35. Once your order has been reviewed, you will receive an email notification indicating whether your order can be filled (based on availability of records, eligibility, etc.)."

Comment: I have tried again. I am getting the expected answer. Did you try this:var orderID= orderIdText.substring(orderIdText.lastIndexOf("is")+3, orderIdText.lastIndexOf(".",orderIdText.indexOf("\r")))